# How to ignore/remove file which is staged and in local branch without removing from other local branch?

Tags: git, github

> I want to remove 2 files from local branch B1 which are staged for commit without removing from another local branch B2.
>   When i did git Checkout filename to ignore the file  it gives error saying "did not match any files known to git".
>   How can i safely remove this files from current branch without removing from another local branch??

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want. Did you try git rm --cached ?